# (JAVA) Comparing a word entered by a user with another word contained in a text file

Tags: java, file, swing, file-io, awt

I'd like to verify if my text file already contains a word entered by a user in a textfield. When the user clicks on Validate if the word is already in the file, the user will enter another word. If the word is not in the file, it will add the word. Each line of my file contains one word. I put System.out.println to see what is being printed and it always say that the word does not existe in the file, but it's not true... Can you tell me what's wrong?

Thanks.

```
class ActionCF implements ActionListener
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

            str = v[0].getText(); 
            BufferedWriter out;
            BufferedReader in;
            String line;
            try 
            {

                out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:/File.txt",true));
                in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/File.txt"));

                while (( line = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    if ((in.readLine()).contentEquals(str))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Yes");

                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("No");

                        out.newLine();

                        out.write(str);

                        out.close();

                    } 

               }
            }
            catch(IOException t)
            {
                System.out.println("There was a problem:" + t);

            }   
        }

    }
```

Comment: What are the contents of the file you are using, what is your input, and what does the console spit out?

Comment: have you tried this using scanner?i always prefer scanner whenever its possible.

Comment: Hi Nicholas. Each line of text file contains 1 word. The user enters a word in a textField, and I want to know if this word is already in the text file and if not, add it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're calling `in.readLine()` twice, once in the `while` loop and again in the conditional. This is causing it to skip every other line. Also, you want to use [`String.contains`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead of [`String.contentEquals`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contentEquals%28java.lang.CharSequence%29), since you're just checking to see if the line *contains* the word.  Furthermore, you want to wait until the entire file has been searched before you decide the word wasn't found. So try this:

```
//try to find the word
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/File.txt"));
boolean found = false;
while (( line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.contains(str))
    {
        found = true;
        break; //break out of loop now
    }
}
in.close();

//if word was found:
if (found)
{
    System.out.println("Yes");
}
//otherwise:
else
{
    System.out.println("No");

    //wait until it's necessary to use an output stream
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:/File.txt",true));
    out.newLine();
    out.write(str);
    out.close();
}
```

(Exception handling omitted from my example)

**EDIT:** I just re-read your question - if every line contains exactly one word, then [`equals`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) or [`equalsIgnoreCase`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) would work instead of `contains`, making sure to call [`trim`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) on `line` before testing it, to filter out any whitespace:

```
if (line.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(str))
...
```

Comment: Another thing worth pointing out is that if the file contains two lines that are not the word that was input, the first one will close the `BufferedWriter` and the second one will throw an Exception (causing the while loop to terminate), as it will be attempting to write to a closed `BufferedWriter`.